# Regular expression for search all option tags .?

Tags: html, regex, eclipse

here is my text

```
<OPTION / value/3D70>Airport</OPTION>
<OPTION value/3D81>Akuressa</OPTION>
<OPTION value/3D32>Ambalangoda</OPTION>
<OPTION value/3D65>Ambalantota</OPTION>
```

I need to get only Values ex : **Airport,Akuressa**
so please give me a regular expression code to search all

```
<OPTION [ANYVALUES NUMBER OR LETTERS] >
```

then i can search in eclipse and replace with null and get only values.

EDIT: :

I Got it

```
<OPTION (.|\r\n)*\>
```

thanks all :-)

this is helped me a lot

[regex online tool](http://rubular.com/r/COVTptKtEU)

Comment: That doesn't look like valid HTML. Also... in which language?

Comment: I got these from another program.thats why need to filter those values. :-)

Comment: HTML but they added some parts to secure code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it stays in that format, you could read one line at a time and apply this regex to it:

```
(?<=>)([^<]*)(?=<)
```

If you want the text after OPTION, I wouldn't go with what you have...it looks wrong.  I'd go with this:

```
<OPTION ([^>]*)>
```

Comment: Your question was confusing, I hope you realize.  You said you were looking for "Airport" and "Akuressa", but then you post a regex that finds ... I'm not sure what, but certainly not just the tag values...

Comment: i need to get only airport and akuressa OR delete option tags :-)

Answer (score 0):

I Got it :-)

```
<OPTION (.|\r\n)*\>
```